# what is the purpose of these symbols in Python? ♀ ♂

Tags: python, symbols

`print('\f')` outputs ♀ (female symbol) and `print('\v')` outputs ♂ (male symbol). Since these symbols are
not part of the ASCII characters, why does python output them?

Bonus question: I get why `'\f'` is the `f`emale symbol, but why is `'\v'` the male?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: \f does not stand for female

Comment: @venky_ Windows 10 pro.

Comment: More to the point, which code page?

Comment: @tripleee am using code page 437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\f` stands for Form Feed while `\v` stands for Vertical Tabulator.

These are included because they are included with your font. There is also `\t`, `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: More generally, many code pages and legacy character encodings assign graphical glyphs to *all* the control characters (ASCII 0-31). They can be used to display characters in contexts where no terminal emulator etc interprets them as control codes.